# how to import multiple folders in bloomrpc

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using grpc for my project. I need to import proto files from multiple folders. If I import directly it is not working. How can I import them all at the same time?

I would appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is very simple. I found a way [here](https://github.com/bloomrpc/bloomrpc/issues/102#issuecomment-515361276):

I've tried your example protos my self and i've got the same error.
Although i then noticed that you have something wrong in your protos/exampleService.proto.

If both of the protos lives within the same folder then your import should be only import "exampleModel.proto"; without the protos prefix`. If you try to load it like this it works.

**The reason why your protoc works is because you probably have set an import path resolution.**

- `So if you don't want to change your import, you need to tell bloomrpc the same thing.`
- `Open the import path option on the sidebar`
- `Add the absolute path the to folder one step back to the protos folder.`
- `Try importing again`